# Make a push button look disabled/grayed according to my requirement

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, button

I have a Server/Client application. The Server has push buttons for each client. When a client is connected, the push button becomes enabled and you can click on the button. When the button is clicked, a new window appears showing information of this specific client like IP Address, Port Number etc.

Now, what I want is that I may be able to disable the push button as soon as the client goes down or becomes In Active. And when the client connects again, the button must again get enabled to be clicked by the user.

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality? Any help/suggestion is welcome.

**Edit:**
I've tried with `EnableWindow` but I get `Run time check failure #3 variable used without being initialized` error.

Below is the code snippet:

```
HWND hWndButton[10];
       case WM_CREATE:
          {
           SetTimer(hwnd,IDT_TIMER1,10000, NULL);    
           for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
           {
              hWndButton[i] =    CreateWindowEx(NULL,"BUTTON",buttonCaption,WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                                             30*i,30,70,20,hwnd,   (HMENU)buttonNumber,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
           }
          } 
       break;
       case WM_TIMER: 
          switch(wParam) 
             { 
                case IDT_TIMER1: 
                   {
                     EnableWindow(hWndButton[8],FALSE);
                   }
            break;
             }
       break;
```

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: "I've tried with EnableWindow but I get `Run time check failure #3 variable used without being initialized` error." So... did you initialize the variable?  The error message tells you what's wrong.

Comment: The error is for HWND hWndButton[10], declared at the start of the orogram and its get initializes when WM_CREATE is called.  and I've never initialized HWND in many of my codes and the code work fine without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291.aspx) function with the handle of the button.

Comment: Please have a look at the Edit

Comment: The edit does not make it clear whether hWndButton is a global variable or a local variable. The error message suggests you made it a local variable, which can't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Making it the global variable solved the probllem but I still can't figure out how did this happen.

Comment: If hWndButton is a local array you get a new uninitialized array every time the wndproc function is called. The array is destroyed (and you lose the hwnd's you stored in it) when wndproc returns.